# Comparing against list of dates

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

Have a small problem with LINQ queries.

Basically I have two lists, filled with dates.

```
List<DateTime> start = GetListOfStartDates();
List<DateTime> end = GetListOfEndDates();
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
```

How do I perform a LINQ query, where I compare a date against the start and end date, basically in sense:

```
(start <= date && end >= date)
```

Obviously I understand that they are lists, so this does not work, how do I compare a single date against two lists of dates? Basically doing a between for a set of dates.

The start indices will always match end indices, `start[7]` will always match `end[7]`. I'm attempting to turn a mysql `between`-query into LINQ. So I'm looking for IF the given "date" is within any start-end pair.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what the end result should be, based on the contents of the two lists?

Comment: How are start date and end date related? Are they always related by index position? For example, start[0] is always the start date related to end[0]? Or can any start date be matched up with any end date?

Comment: They are indexed, start[0] will -ALWAYS- match end[0]. Basically attempting to create a LINQ query that does "BETWEEN" on the lists.

Comment: Now, there's some good information, Mike. Now edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting your question correctly (see my comment above) I think you are better off doing this as a for loop instead of a LINQ query. I'd do something like this:

```
public bool DateFallsInRange(IEnumerable<DateTime> startDates, IEnumerable<DateTime> endDates)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < startDates.Count; index++)
    {
        if ((startDates[index] <= compareDate) && (compareDate <= endDates[index])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, I might have tried forcing the LINQ on a bit too much. This definitely is a good enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Another interpretation of OP's goal:

```
bool b = start.Zip(end, (x, y) => new { Start = x, End = y })
              .Any(z => z.Start <= date && z.End >= date);
```

Or you can use `All()` instead, that depends on your logic.

Comment: This is just making sure the date falls after the last start date and before the first end date. It doesn't do the item-by-item comparison that he seems to be looking for.

Comment: @Tim: I'm really not sure what exactly does OP want to achieve. I upvoted your answer because it looks like the most close to OP's need, from how do I understand it.

Comment: @Mike: I found a pure LINQ solution for your question.

Comment: +1 for using `.Zip(...)`. I think however that `.Any(...)` would be a better match to what's being asked.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, whenever I do these types of comparisons (if a value is within a given span) I usually try to write them as mathematicians do (eg. `lowerExclusive < value <= upperInclusive`). In this case it would probably be `z.Start <= date && date <= z.End`. IMHO better readability (the "arrow of time" points consistently to the right) and therefore less error prone.

Comment: @Christoffer: Sure, agree, same for me. But in this case I just copy-pasted from OP's question for better readability from his stand point.

Answer (score 0):

the start and end list index must be the same?
Example:

```
start|end
[0]1940|1950
[1]1890|1930
```

the date 1931 should pass because 1890<1931<1950?
or should not pass because 1931<1940 and 1931>1930?